# Why isn't the stylesheet (added via jQuery) applied?

Tags: jquery, css, debugging, lazy-loading, bookmarklet

This is a fairly complicated question - at least for me.

I have written a bookmarklet (yes, I do such things when "necessary") that works fine on every page I tested so far. But today I came across one where it does not work and I do not know why.

The bookmarklet adds an inline stylesheet the end of the head-tag. And then it adds a div to the end of the body with an id that is also in the stylesheet.

Normally this works, but I realize that it is a bit by chance. It is a grey zone as far as I know, but maybe someone knows better than me and at least can give some advice? (I can apply direct styles, yes, but I would like to avoid it if possible since it is a maintenance burden.)

The bookmark is here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/848981/it/cw/cw.html

And the page where it does not work is here:
http://www.professionalsagainstect.com/index.html

Update: Some info to make it easier to look into it. After clicking the bookmarklet:

- Look at the end of the head tag for the stylesheet. It gets a title attribute starting with "cw.css ...".
- The div-tag where it should be applied is at the end of the body-tag and has id="shield-findword72789".

*Update 2*:
It looks like the stylesheet I add is not beeing applied when there is something like this in *body* part:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data:text/css.">
```

To work around this I applied the most important styles directly to the elements I added insted.

Comment: One thing I notice is that your `div#shield-findword72789` has a height of 0px, although it is present in the DOM. Are you normally assigning that div a height via JavaScript?

Comment: @Michael: No, the height is set in the style sheet. The style sheet is added to the end of the head tag (by JavaScript), see above.

Answer (score 0):

The `href` attribute needs to be defined **after** the `link` element is appended to the `head`, like this:

```
function foo()
  {
  /* get head element */
  var head=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

  /* create link element */
  var qUnitCSS = document.createElement("link");

  /* rel and type attributes required for lazy loading */
  qUnitCSS.rel="stylesheet";
  qUnitCSS.type="text/css";

  /* append link element */
  head.appendChild(qUnitCSS);

  /* define link href after DOM insertion to lazy load */
  qUnitCSS.href="http://qunitjs.com/resources/qunit.css";    
  }()
```

Here is the bookmarklet version:

```
javascript:void(function foo(){var head=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];var qUnitCSS = document.createElement("link");qUnitCSS.rel="stylesheet";qUnitCSS.type="text/css";head.appendChild(qUnitCSS);qUnitCSS.href="http://qunitjs.com/resources/qunit.css";}() )
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. Yes it needs to be applied after the link, but that was not the problem. In bookmarklets you will meet all kind of trouble on this side. In the end I decided to add some routines to add all needed styles directly on each element (with "!important").

So I wrote some elisp functions to take a style sheet and translate it into jQuery functions doing this. (This also makes the loading faster and gives the possibility to make everything into a bookmarklet that users can save. Maybe the main browsers will all follow the W3C recommandations so they may use bookmarklets again. ;-) )

Comment: @Leo Thanks for the update Leo. Good to know elisp came in handy, I was thinking about using it for text processing.

Comment: Good luck! For me it is a great tool since I do a lot of different things.